# Celery Worker is offline

Tags: python, django, celery

I am running a celery worker

```
foreman run python manage.py celery worker -E --maxtasksperchild=1000
```

And a celerymon

```
foreman run python manage.py celerymon
```

as well as celerycam

```
foreman run python manage.py celerycam
```

The django admin shows that my worker is offline and all tasks remain in the delayed state. I have tried killing and restarting it several times but it does not seem to be online.

Here is my configuration

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'amqplib'
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=0
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = 0

BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('AMQP_URL')

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'database'

CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 14400
```

Comment: Did you [run the scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler)? `foreman run python manage.py celery beat`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `--loglevel=info` or `--loglevel=debug` to your celery command and seen what it outputs?

Comment: if you do `ps aux | grep celery` do you see celery as a currently running process?

Comment: @Ngenator Thanks. I did run celery worker with the -B option. Isn't that the same thing.

Comment: @Hodson I do have ``--loglevel=debug`` set and ``--verbosity=3``. It does not show any explicit error. 

@rednaw It does show as a current running process

Comment: I might have got it to work after removing monkey patching for gevents commands I was using in my `manage.py` for using `grequests`

Comment: @PratikMandrekar I didn't see that on the commands you posted, but yes, as long as you are using 1 worker that would work too. Glad to hear you figured it out though.